# When my friend tries to join me it say "outdated server"

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend has tried to join me many times on Minecraft it says he is on version 1.13.0.1 and i'm on version 1.11.4. It has gone to us both deleting, it feels like nothing's working.

Comment: I had to download something by Xbox to play. I forget what is was exactly but you have to download something

Answer (score 1):

You need to be on the same version to play together.